# Generate alphanumeric strings sequentially

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm trying to create a loop to generate and print strings as follows:

1. Alphanumeric characters only:
2. 0-9 are before A-Z, which are before a-z,
3. Length goes up to 4 characters.

So, it would print:

1. all strings from 0-z
2. then from 00-zz
3. then from 000-zzz
4. then from 0000-zzzz

then it stops.

Comment: It's too difficult to understand your question... would a07z be a legal string or not?

Comment: Yes. All alphanumeric strings length 1-4 are legal

Comment: So when you say 0-9 are before A-Z you mean that 0000 should come before A000?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

chars = digits + ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase

for n in range(1, 4 + 1):
    for comb in product(chars, repeat=n):
        print ''.join(comb)
```

This first makes a string of all the numbers, uppercase letters, and lowercase letters.

Then, for each length from 1-4, it prints every possible combination of those numbers and letters.

Keep in mind this is A LOT of combinations -- 62^4 + 62^3 + 62^2 + 62.

Comment: That's a cool solution. Also a cool thing to do is to make it a generator instead of directly printing the strings.

Comment: I know it's a ton of combinations, I was mostly doing it just for testing purposes. I cut it down to 3 characters instead of 4

Comment: Yeah, he said he wanted a "loop that printed strings" so that's what I gave him.

Comment: FYI `ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase == ascii_letters`

Answer (score 1):

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product
chars = digits + ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase

def give_me_next(lst):
        lst = lst[::-1]
        change_next = False
        change = True
        n = 0
        for x in lst:
                if change_next == True:
                        change_next = False
                        pos = chars.find(x)
                        try:
                                a =  chars[pos+1]
                                lst = list(lst)
                                lst[n] = a
                                lst = "".join(lst)
                                x = a
                        except:
                                lst = list(lst)
                                lst[n] = '0'
                                lst = "".join(lst)
                                change_next = True
                                x = '0'

                pos = chars.find(x)
                try:
                        a =  chars[pos+1]
                        if change == True:
                                lst = list(lst)
                                lst[n] = a
                                lst = "".join(lst)
                                change = False
                except:
                        lst = list(lst)
                        lst[n] = '0'
                        lst = "".join(lst)
                        change_next = True

                n = n + 1

        lst = lst[::-1]
        return lst

a=  give_me_next('zzzzz')
while True:
        a =  give_me_next(a)
        print a
```

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the answer given before me using `product` since looking at its implementation in the python documentation it seem to span the entire thing into a list in memory before starting to yield the results.

This is very bad for your case since, as agf himself said, the number of permutation here is huge (well over a million). For this case the `yield` statement was created - so that huge lists could be dynamically generated rather than spanned in memory (I also disliked the wasteful `range` where `xrange` is perfectly applicable).

I'd go for a solution like this:

```
def generate(chars, length, prefix = None):
    if length < 1:
        return
    if not prefix:
        prefix = ''
    for char in chars:
        permutation = prefix + char
        if length == 1:
            yield permutation
        else:
            for sub_permutation in generate(chars, length - 1, prefix = permutation):
                yield sub_permutation
```

This way, all that spans in memory is a recursive stack "n" deep, where "n" is the length of your permutations (4 in this case) and only a single element is returned each time.

chars is the set of chars to choose from, length is 4 and the use is rather similar to products, except that it doesn't span the whole list in memory during run time.

Comment: It says in the `product` description -- "This function is equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory:" All of the tools in `itertools` work that way, it's the entire purpose of the module.

Comment: I think for very small ranges, `range` is actually _less_ wasteful than `xrange`.

Answer (score 0):

I coded this today. It does exactly what you want **and more**. It's extendable as well

```
def lastCase (lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        if ( lst[i] != '_' ):
            return False
    return True


l = [''] * 4 #change size here if needed. I used 4
l[0] = '0'
index = 0

while ( not lastCase(l) ):

    if ( ord(l[index]) > ord('_') ):
        l[index] = '0'
        index += 1
        while( l[index] == '_' ):
            l[index] = '0'
            index += 1
        if (l[index] == ''):
            l[index] = '0'

    #print or process generated string
    print(''.join(l))

    l[index] = chr(ord(l[index]) +1)

    if ( ord(l[index]) > ord('9') and ord(l[index]) < ord('A') ):
        l[index] = 'A'
    elif ( ord(l[index]) > ord('Z') and ord(l[index]) < ord('_')  ): 
        l[index] = '_'

    index = 0

print (''.join(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the simplest solution to me:

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase

chars = digits + ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase
all_str = [''.join([a]) for a in chars] \
        + [''.join([a,b]) for a in chars for b in chars] \
        + [''.join([a,b,c]) for a in chars for b in chars for c in chars] \
        + [''.join([a,b,c,d]) for a in chars for b in chars for c in chars for d in chars]

print(all_str)
print("Number of strings:", len(all_str))
```

[Example for strings with maximum 2 characters.](https://repl.it/repls/DentalStrongClick)

Of course, there may be a way to generalize to any max number of characters per string, but since you have a specific need for strings up to 4 characters, it's fine.